# Catan - Mixing German base game with English extensions and expansions

Tags: catan

Has anyone tried to use the German edition of the Settlers of Catan base game (published by Kosmos) with the English editions of expansions and extensions (published by Mayfair)? Is it possible? (How much) Are they compatible?

I am asking because I have a Serbian edition of the base game which is an exact copy of the German edition, but I don't speak German, so I would like to have English editions of expansions/extensions. But I also wouldn't like to have to buy the English edition of the base game also.

Answer (score 2):

Per se it should be possible to mix german/english or in your case serbian/english editions. But you should have a close look which edition you're buying (also depending on which edition you already own) there are even (minor) compatibility problems inbetween english editions (this should apply on german editions too)
Also hava a look on this [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1651/7650).

Besides the form factor english editions of the game have those (in my eyes ugly) white borders around their tiles. Additionally other graphics are used (in my opinion those are shrill compared to the german ones)

I hope I could help you slightly.