# Have there been revisions to the rules of Catan?

Tags: house-rules, catan

I have been playing catan for at least 6 years, following a trip to the Netherlands where I encountered the game. For the whole time, I have played that, on a role of 7, the player cannot build or deploy dev cards, in addition to the robber business.

Recently I have checked the rules site and been disabused of this notion. Have the rules of Catan been changed at all since its creation?

I have a strong recollection of checking the rule book and verifying that one could not use dev cards on a 7 role, but I could well be delusional.

I enjoy playing with this set of house rules, but it is useful to be familiar with the RAW when you play with new people.

Comment: While there have been a few various changes; the rule you describe was never a rule. It is not uncommon for Catan to be played with various house rules; so it could just be that the people who taught you the game taught you their own house rules as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is worth an explicit answer, but I agree with @ConMan and @Gendolkari in the comments of the question and @JoeW's answer.

Yes, there have been many minor changes in the rules.

No, you have never been restricted from taking other actions following a roll of a 7. You always get your turn as normal.

One possible source of confusion in this area is the limit on playing 1 development card per turn. Using a knight before your roll in many ways replicates the actions of rolling a 7 (excluding the hand size based card loss). It is possible these two things have been conflated in a house rule.

[Annotated Rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/40528/settlers-catan-completely-annotated-rules-almanac) From the linked annotated Rules from 1st Edition.

> (3) After discarding occurs, you also steal 1 Resource Card at random from a player who has a settlement or city adjacent to this new hex. The player who is robbed holds his Resource Card hand face down. You then take 1 at random. If there are 2 or more players with buildings there, you may choose from which one to steal. 
>   The robber must be moved. You may not choose to leave the robber in the same
>   hex. **After moving the robber, your turn continues with the trade phase.**

Comment: I think I may have misread the above rule as skipping the build phase, as we always explicitly allowed trading. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there has been many updates to the rules over the years and they are generally updated each time a new version was released and they have made notes of that in the rule book. For reference there is a question on this site asking about changes for 5th edition as there was a note in the rule book about them but not what they where.

[What are the rules updates for Catan in the 5th edition? Are there any?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24012/what-are-the-rules-updates-for-catan-in-the-5th-edition-are-there-any)

Comment: While it's true that the rules have been updated, as far as I can tell there has never been a rule stating that rolling a 7 means you don't build or trade. The main change from 3rd edition to 4th was allowing the robber to be placed on the desert.

Comment: Yeah I've never heard of that rule, at least as far back as 2e